# Laravel 4 Controller Route - Get Route with Numerical Parameters and Other Specific Parameters

Tags: php, laravel-4, controller, routes

Looking for some insight on this.

I am trying to define a route controller in a Laravel 4 application that does the following things.

- Handles the route `user/{userid}`
- Handles the route `user/new`

I cannot figure out a way to make both happen simultaneously.

My controller and route look like this:

```
Route::controller('user', 'UserController');
```

```
class UserController extends BaseController {

    public function getIndex($user_id) {
        $user = User::find($user_id);
        return View::make('user')
            ->with('user', $user);
    }

    public function getNew() {
        return View::make('create_user');
    }
}
```

To me, that should work, but I get a 404 when trying to go to `user/1`.  Oddly enough, `user/new` still takes me to `create_user` as it should.  The `user.blade.php` view and `create_user.blade.php` view both exist in the root of `views`, so that isn't the problem either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing `Route::controller('user', 'UserController');` you can do the following in your routes:

```
Route::get('user/new', 'UserController@getNew');
Route::get('user/{user_id}', 'UserController@getIndex');
```

OR you can also do the following:

```
Route::get('user/{user_id}', 'UserController@getIndex');
Route::controller('user', 'UserController');
```

Comment: Is there a way to do that all in a controller though? I know its trivial, but I'm trying to keep it consistent and neat. Everything else runs through controllers.

Comment: I don't know if it can be completely done with `Route::controller` or not, but I've added another way which utilizes `Route::controller` also.

Comment: When I go to `user/new` with the second method, it passes "new" to `UserController@getIndex`. I was able to find a workaround for my purposes, by adding to your second answer. I added `->where('id', '[0-9]+');` to the end of the `get` route and it works for both! :)